# Wakanda upgrade to v11: Browser can't get fonts from Wakanda

Tags: wakanda

I am upgrading from Wakanda v10 to v11. When I access my site, the browser (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) is looking for fonts and Wakanda is not delivering them. The image shows the console errors.

I tried creating a folder `/walib/etc..` at the webroot and adding a `.ttf` file at the name and location specified but it does not work. I suspect the `/walib/` URI is managed by a request handler- the directory didn't exist and things like the data browser use that URI. None of these errors happen when I run the site in v10. Any advice on what to try?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I tried running the solution on another machine and am getting the same errors when I load pages. Also, the version is the latest Enterprise stable release (v11 build 11.196912).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. There is a serverside function `getWalibFolder()` that returns the location of the `walib` folder. It is an actual location and on my Mac it is inside of the Wakanda Enterprise Server package contents.

I found the fonts in the v10 server application's package contents and copied over the fonts to the v11 server application package. The errors are gone and the issue is resolved.